# How can I split a polygon into two equal parts along a N-S axis?

Tags: postgis, polygon-creation, splitting

I have a PostGIS database with a table called 'sites' that includes a field sitename and a field geometry.

If I select, e.g.

```
select sitename, ST_AsGeoJSON(geometry) from sites limit 1;
```

I get:

> Plot 7     | {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":
>     [[[-111.974951718315,33.0745275800293,353],
>     [-111.974935360975,33.0745276003588,353],
>     [-111.974935370263,33.0745546649121,353],
>     [-111.974951727608,33.0745546445826,353],[-111.974951718315,33.0745275800293,353]]]}

These are rectangles oriented very close to N-S. I would like to divide each plot in half along (or close to) its N-S axis. Is there an easy way to do this?

Solutions in PostGIS-SQL preferred. Ultimately I plan to write insert statements like

```
insert into sites (name, geometry) 
   values ('Site 1 E', (select ??east half of geometry?? from sites where name = 'Site 1'))
```

The closest I've gotten is [ST_Split](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Split.html), which requires the polygon as well as the 'blade' (line used to split), but it is not clear how I can compute the blade from the geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to divide each plot in half along (or close to) its N-S axis. Is there an easy way to do this? [...] can compute the blade from the geometry.

Something like?

```
xmin+((xmax-xmin)/2)
```

Here we create a sample data set `foo`. In it we create a polygon, we calculate the xaxis to bisect the polygon with, and we create the blade.

Then we do the bisection and display the results with `ST_AsText`

```
WITH foo AS (
  SELECT geom, blade
  FROM ST_MakeEnvelope(-10,-10,10,10) AS geom
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT ST_xMin(geom) + (ST_xMax(geom) - ST_xMin(geom)) / 2 ) AS axis(x)
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL ST_MakeLine(
    ST_MakePoint(axis.x, ST_yMin(geom)),
    ST_MakePoint(axis.x, ST_yMax(geom))
  ) AS blade
)
SELECT ST_AsText(geom),
  ST_AsText(blade),
  ST_AsText( ST_Split(geom, blade) )
FROM foo;
                   st_astext                    |       st_astext        |                                                st_astext                                                 
------------------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POLYGON((-10 -10,-10 10,10 10,10 -10,-10 -10)) | LINESTRING(0 -10,0 10) | GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POLYGON((-10 -10,-10 10,0 10,0 -10,-10 -10)),POLYGON((0 10,10 10,10 -10,0 -10,0 10)))
```

Comment: How about `ST_Centroid` ?

Comment: @dbaston that sounds more cpuintensive, I showed you how to read xMin/xMax/yMin/yMax but for the purpose of creating a blade to split something, you need only two of the four.

Comment: Maybe it sounds CPU-intensive, but it isn't, especially in the context of ST_Split.  Whether it should be used depends on the requirements, I guess.  I was suggesting centroid in order to get an equal-area split.

Comment: Just noticed that the inputs are strictly rectangles, which makes my above point irrelevant.

Comment: @EvanCarroll this was great, I learned a lot ... thanks! Though would be awesome if the query generated insert statements. (for future reference) to generate an insert statement I had to 1) `ST_Dump(ST_Split` to the polygons, but 2) had to use `ST_xmax` to sort  3) and remove split `({1},`, `({2}` and `)` generated from the dump; 4) `ST_SetSRID` to avoid error; my final query https://gist.github.com/dlebauer/f586e380fa4cfadc25551cd1df487b7d got me most of the way but still required spreadsheet-foo.

Comment: Note that `xmin+((xmax-xmin)/2) = xmin+xmax/2-xmin/2 = ((xmax+xmin)/2)`.